# Does a recursive call to a function instantiate it?

Tags: vba, excel, recursion, callstack

I am trying to understand the below code snippet for counting up
How does the msgbox store all the values for n?

Is it because when countup(n-1) is called,it instantiates the function and then associates the n value with a msgbox instance?

```
Option Explicit

Sub countup(n As Integer)   
   If (n > 1) Then
      countup (n - 1)
   End If
   MsgBox (n)
End Sub

Sub myprogram()
   Call countup(10)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @EdPlunkett mentioned, *instantiation* has nothing to do with it. That deals with creating new objects. This is about calling the same function from within itself, or *recursion*.

The program execution looks like this:

```
countup(10) called
  -> countup(9) called
    -> countup(8) called
       -> countup(7) called
          -> countup(6) called
            -> countup(5) called
              -> countup(4) called
                ->countup(3) called
                  ->countup(2) called
                     -> MsgBox (1)
                  -> MsgBox (2)
                -> MsgBox (3)
              -> MsgBox (4)
            -> MsgBox (5)
          -> MsgBox (6)
        -> MsgBox (7)
      -> MsgBox (8)
    -> MsgBox (9)
  -> MsgBox (10)
```

Indented 2 spaces each time to show a recursive call, or stepping back out.

As you can see, the call stack increases until it is a full 9 levels deep (due to `If (n > 1)`) before it executes the very first `MsgBox`. The code then returns back to the previous caller, which calls its `MsgBox` and continues the entire way back up the call stack, returning to each previous caller.

Finally, we return back to `countup(10)`, which executes the final MsgBox(10), at which point we return to `myprogram()`.

Comment: How are the n values stored, isn't n supposed to be static? So by the time it reaches MsgBox(n), wouldn't it show just 1, but instead it shows 10 till 1.

Comment: How is countup(10) associated with MsgBox(10), by order of execution?

Comment: @What happened to your comment?

Comment: @null My comment incorrectly mentioned that it passed the variable `n` ByVal. I deleted it.

Comment: @null I've updated the answer to include some commentary on what is actually happening with regard to the call stack. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The program starts by calling your subroutine/function `countup` and passing in the value of 10.  That value is then in the variable `n` that is the parameter to `countup`.  The function tests the value of `n` and calls `countup` again with `n - 1` (9 in the first time `countup` is called).  `countup` keeps getting called, deeper and deeper, with `n - 1` until we get down to 1.  Then we start unravelling.  The deepest layer to unravel received the `n` with 1 in it so it then calls `MsgBox (n)`, which displays 1.  As we unravel to the next level `n = 2` and so `MsgBox` displays 2.  And so on, all the way back up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that "instantiate" isn't the correct term, I think it may be a useful way of thinking of what is happening. If you change your countup subroutine slightly (see below) so that it now also stores the parameter it is passed, you really would have up to 10 instances of the variable called "storeN", each one with a different value. You would only be able to access the storeN in the "current" version of countup. But the rest are there and will be restored back into the "earlier" calls of countup, as the recursion unwinds.

This is essentially exactly what is happening with the variable n. There *are* different "instances" of n that brought back to see daylight as the recursion unwinds. And this why MsgBox displays a different value of n for each call.

So I think your own answer is basically correct.

```
Option Explicit

Sub countup(n As Integer)   
   Dim storeN as Integer
   storeN = n
   If (n > 1) Then
      countup (n - 1)
   End If
   MsgBox (n)
End Sub

Sub myprogram()
   Call countup(10)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

With handing over a parameter to a procedure like `countup(n As Integer)` actual is the short version of `countup(byRef n As Integer)`. If you change the value of `n` within your sub the value of the calling `n` is changed too.

Comment: However, since in this example, n is never actually changed - it all works.